# How to make a JTable Column changes it color According to Specific Values from the Database

Tags: swing, jdbc, jtable, client-server

I'm Building a **Client/server** Desktop Application.

I wanted to know if it is possible to make a **JTable Column** Changes its **color** according to specific values from the database (oracle).

- **Red**= "Refused".
- **Green**="Accepted".
- **yellow**="Quarantine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom column renderer for this:

```
public class ColorColumnRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
   Color bkgndColor, fgndColor;

   public ColorColumnRenderer(Color bkgnd, Color foregnd) {
      super(); 
      bkgndColor = bkgnd;
      fgndColor = foregnd;
   }

   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
        (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
         boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
   {
      Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent
         (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

      cell.setBackground( bkgndColor );
      cell.setForeground( fgndColor );

      return cell;
   }
}
```

You can use that renderer like this (example for a single column):

```
TableColumn tm = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
tm.setCellRenderer(new ColorColumnRenderer(Color.lightGray, Color.blue));
```

Once you have the color changing code you can create a [listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) which listens for the value changes to the table model and by checking the changes you can apply the colors you want to specific columns.

Comment: no: a) misses selection b) dont change the renderer, instead let the renderer change its colors depending on value

Answer (score 2):

Use an appropriate [renderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).